# Chrome mobile doesn't update css styles properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, scroll

I want to make a fix positioned sticky element that sticks to the bottom of the page when scrolling the page to top.

It works ok on desktop Chrome browser, but doesn't on mobile. Can't find out the exact problem. Is it chrome bug, my code is wrong?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        position: 0
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }


    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    handleScroll = () => {
        const {scrollTop, scrollHeight} = document.documentElement;
        const scroll = scrollHeight - scrollTop - window.innerHeight;
        if (scroll <= 100) {
            this.setState({position: 100 - scroll});
        } else if (this.state.position !== 0) {
            this.setState({position: 0});
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
             <section>
                 <div className="box" style={{
                    bottom: this.state.position
                 }}>
                   STICKY BOX
                </div>
             </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the pen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sAs59/pen/bKZwwE?editors=0110)

Comment: indeed seems like a bug, as if it's not re-painting. the weird thing is that it re-paints when you hover over the elements in the devtools. seems like a GPU acceleration issue